# Why does setting desynchronized and alpha to false on my canvas change the colors?

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl, alpha

I was messing around with the available [canvas context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext) flags for my WebGL application, and I noticed that setting `desynchronized` to true along with `alpha` to false when performing `getContext()`, like this:

```
const canvasContext = canvasElem.getContext("webgl2", { 
  alpha: false,
  desynchronized: true
});
```

Changes the colors to be exactly as I set them.

That is, if I try to draw with the color `#FF0000`, it will draw exactly that. It makes sense to me why this would occur with setting `alpha` to false, because it prevents blending with the page's background (or whatever else is behind the canvas), but setting `alpha` alone doesn't seem to cause this effect.

Rather, you must have both in order for the canvas colors to not blend with the background of the page. I'm curious why this is.

Comment: Sounds like your shader is writing transparency or factoring in lighting when you don't want it to. Writing solid unlit red will be exactly that, regardless of those settings on the canvas. Would probably be good to share the code you're using to do the render call or exhibit the colour shift you see.

Comment: Well, the shader is extremely simple. All it does is draw a rectangle with the color `1, 0, 0, 1`. But it is drawing on top of a cleared back buffer that is cleared with the color `0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0`. And the `blendFunc` is `SRC_ALPHA, ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA`. But I'm more curious why setting the `alpha` property alone doesn't disable this blending. I have to _also_ add the `desynchronized` flag. Isn't that strange?

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. Your `clearColor(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0)` has no transparency so setting alpha: true or false should not have any effect: your clear color is opaque so you can't see the background of the page. I can't reproduce this in FF.